# multiprocessing for multi columns with same function

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, pool

I have a csv file with 100 thousands rows.Columns = ['NAME','X','Y','angle1','angle2'......'angle360']

```
  NAME   X  Y  angle1  angle2 ... angel360
0    a  13  1       1       5 ...    2
1    b  12  7       4       5 ...    3
2    c  23  2       1       6 ...    1
3    d  32  6       1       2 ...    7
4    e  31  6       2       3 ...    4
5    f  24  3       3       2 ...    1
6    g  14  1       5       3 ...    2
7    h  14  2       8       3 ...    7
8    i  75  4       2       7 ...    5
...
```

I need to calculate each angle with rule : `(X-angle[i])/Y` and save the result to a new column named result[i]

```
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool,cpu_count
import numpy as np
def parallelize_dataframe(df, func):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
    pool = Pool(num_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df

def calculate(df,i):
    df['result'+str(i)] = (df['X']-df['angle'+str(i)])/df['Y']
    return df

def result(df):
    for i in range(360):
        df = calculate(df,i)
    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_cores = cpu_count() - 2  # number of cores on your machine
    num_partitions = 10 * num_cores  # number of partitions to split dataframe

    df = pd.read_csv("C:\user\tmp\file.csv")
    parallelize_dataframe(df,result)
```

The result was correct and performance got enhanced but not enough.
It took almost 12 minutes with multiprocessing and 20 minutes without multiprocessing.Any suggestion to improve performance?
Another problem is when process small file (about 7 thousands rows) multiprocessing is slower than single processing.I have no idea why will this happen.

Comment: If order does not matter to you, you can try `imap_unordered(func, iterable[, chunksize])` instead of map. Experiment with `chuncksize` to help give you optimal results. The default `chunksize` is 1 which is likely not optimal for your situation.

Comment: Thanks @MattCremeens ! It got a little improved from 12 mins to 10 mins~~

Comment: a) How many rows exactly?  b) How big is the file on disk? c) How many cores do you use? d) How much RAM do you have? I think you have a memory issue with these timings.

Comment: Hi @Darkonaut a) 101943 rows(if you wanna know this detail) b) 17.3 MB c)12 cores d)16GB . I have another file about 180000 rows which will failed due to out of memory. I also try to solve this issue now...

Comment: Thought you meant multiple of 100k rows.  FYI processing one million rows of a df with your given layout on 4 cores takes less than 16 seconds on my old machine. Just reading in the csv takes more than twice as long. Far away from your 10 minutes. Try with only 4 cores.